# How to add indian holiday list in arshaw's full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I am using [Arshaw's Jquery Calendar](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.0/demos/gcal.html) I need to add the Indian holidays list. An example of US holiday list is given in the [full calendar](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.0/demos/gcal.html). I need to add the link in my script section of the web page as shown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            // US Holidays - I need Indian Holidays instead of this
            events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',

            eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) {
                    $('#loading').show();
                }else{
                    $('#loading').hide();
                }
            }

        });

    });
```

I tried the following link for Indian Holidays in google calendar but its not working :

```
events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.indian%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com&ctz=America/Denver'
```

Comment: Are you using the required gcal.js script?  If so are you able to get the US holiday calendar to work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up your Google Calendar correctly (as per the [instructions](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/))? Try below link:

`http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/indian__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic`